# PGF: Can't change xtick distance

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I create the following chart:

[image]

As you can see, there are too many xtick labels.

I would like to set `xtick distance = 4` (and did specify) that, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Why? I suspect it is to do with `xtick = data` but I don't know the fix.

---

Code for above:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\pgfplotsset{ytick style={draw=none}, xtick style={draw = none}}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{c0}{HTML}{CCCCCC} % gray!40!white
\definecolor{c1}{HTML}{122084}
\definecolor{c2}{HTML}{4e7eba}
\definecolor{c3}{HTML}{81a4c9}
\definecolor{c4}{HTML}{b3c9d8}
\definecolor{c5}{HTML}{d8d9d9}
\definecolor{c6}{HTML}{ff8091}


\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
date, gdp, nfsec, gov, house, nfcorp
%1Q08, 8.7, 119.6, 36.4, 23.0, 60.1
%2Q08, 7.8, 118.1, 35.7, 22.7, 59.7
3Q08, 6.6, 109.6, 31.9, 20.8, 56.8
4Q08, 3.0, 106.9, 31.0, 19.7, 56.0
1Q09, 0.8, 113.9, 32.5, 20.1, 61.1
2Q09, 2.0, 129.6, 37.6, 23.1, 68.6
3Q09, 3.8, 141.1, 41.5, 25.6, 73.6
4Q09, 6.4, 141.4, 42.2, 25.9, 73.0
1Q10, 9.2, 138.9, 41.1, 25.9, 71.5
2Q10, 8.6, 135.0, 39.6, 25.1, 69.9
3Q10, 7.8, 139.1, 40.7, 26.5, 71.5
4Q10, 7.9, 138.9, 40.2, 26.7, 71.7
1Q11, 7.9, 139.5, 40.1, 26.9, 72.2
2Q11, 7.4, 139.1, 39.8, 27.0, 71.9
3Q11, 7.0, 130.4, 36.3, 25.1, 68.8
4Q11, 6.3, 131.5, 36.0, 25.4, 69.9
1Q12, 6.0, 136.3, 37.2, 26.2, 72.6
2Q12, 5.6, 135.9, 36.4, 26.1, 73.1
3Q12, 5.6, 141.9, 37.7, 27.4, 76.4
4Q12, 5.7, 145.1, 38.1, 28.2, 78.3
1Q13, 5.5, 148.3, 38.4, 28.5, 81.1
2Q13, 5.7, 148.2, 37.5, 28.6, 81.8
3Q13, 5.7, 150.9, 37.7, 29.3, 83.6
4Q13, 5.6, 153.3, 38.4, 29.8, 85.0
1Q14, 5.4, 155.6, 38.9, 30.0, 86.5
2Q14, 5.3, 160.8, 40.1, 31.1, 89.4
3Q14, 5.1, 159.0, 39.2, 30.6, 89.0
4Q14, 5.0, 158.5, 39.1, 30.2, 89.0
1Q15, 4.9, 161.5, 39.2, 30.4, 91.6
2Q15, 4.8, 167.5, 40.8, 31.6, 94.9
3Q15, 4.8, 166.6, 40.4, 31.4, 94.6
4Q15, 4.8, 170.4, 41.4, 32.3, 96.5
1Q16, 5.3, 180.8, 44.2, 34.3, 102.0
2Q16, 5.4, 182.2, 45.3, 35.3, 101.4
3Q16, 5.3, 184.3, 46.1, 36.5, 101.5
4Q16, 5.6, 179.3, 45.2, 35.7, 98.1
1Q17, 5.3, 184.5, 46.8, 37.1, 100.5
2Q17, 5.4, 186.3, 47.4, 37.9, 100.9
3Q17, 5.7, 188.6, 47.9, 38.9, 101.6
4Q17, 5.7, 190.2, 48.3, 39.7, 102.0
1Q18, 5.9, 193.0, 49.0, 40.5, 103.4
2Q18, 5.6, 181.3, 46.2, 38.4, 96.6
3Q18, 5.2, 177.7, 45.5, 38.4, 93.7
4Q18, 4.8, 180.9, 47.0, 39.4, 94.4
1Q19, 4.5, 190.5, 49.4, 41.2, 99.8
2Q19, 4.5, 192.2, 50.6, 42.0, 99.6
3Q19, 4.4, 187.9, 49.9, 41.3, 96.5
}\bcharttwelve

\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/new ybar legend/.style={
        /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
            \draw[##1,/tikz/.cd,yshift=-0.05cm, xshift = +0.38cm
            ]
            (0cm,0cm) rectangle (0.6em,0.6em);},},              
}

\pgfplotsset{every non boxed x axis/.append style={x axis line style=-},}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\small
\begin{axis}[ybar stacked/.append style={new ybar legend},
width = 13cm,
height = 6cm,
bar width=3mm,
axis lines=left,
axis y line* = left,
enlarge x limits={0.01, upper},
stack plots = y,
%
% y ticks and label
ylabel={\% of GDP},
ylabel shift = 1pt,
ymin = 1,
ytick distance = 50,
%
% x ticks and label
xtick=data,
xticklabels from table={\bcharttwelve}{date},  
table/x expr = \coordindex,   
xtick distance = 4,                  
x tick label style = {rotate=90},
%
% legend
legend cell align={left},
legend style = {fill = none, draw=none,
    legend columns=2, at={(0.5,1.28)}, anchor=north,
    /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=2em},
},
]
%
% plots
\addplot [new ybar legend, c1, fill, draw opacity = 0]
table [y=gov] from \bcharttwelve \closedcycle;
\addlegendentry{General government};
\addplot [new ybar legend, c3, fill, draw opacity = 0]
table [y=house] from \bcharttwelve \closedcycle;
\addlegendentry{Households};
\addplot [new ybar legend, c5, fill, draw opacity = 0]
table [y=nfcorp] from \bcharttwelve \closedcycle;
\addlegendentry{Non-financial corporations};
\addplot [new ybar legend, c6, fill, draw opacity = 0]
table [y=nfsec] from \bcharttwelve \closedcycle;
\addlegendentry{Non-financial sector};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are right. xrick=data gives a tick for every data point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know if this is the simplest solution but it is a solution. You can use

```
xticklabel={\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{Mod(\ticknum,4)}% 4 is the distance
\ifnum\itest=0
\pgfmathparse{element(\ticknum,0)}\pgfmathresult
\fi},
```

where the pgf function `element`, which has been added here, gets the element from the table. (I guess on the long run this function has to be made more versatile but at least it works.) The mod condition ensures that only every 4th tick gets printed.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{element}{2}{\begingroup
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myindex}{max(0,#1)}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mycol}{#2}%
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\myindex}{[index]\mycol}\of\bcharttwelve%#1=row, #2=column
\edef\pgfmathresult{\pgfplotsretval}%
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult
\endgroup}

\pgfplotsset{ytick style={draw=none}, xtick style={draw = none}}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{c0}{HTML}{CCCCCC} % gray!40!white
\definecolor{c1}{HTML}{122084}
\definecolor{c2}{HTML}{4e7eba}
\definecolor{c3}{HTML}{81a4c9}
\definecolor{c4}{HTML}{b3c9d8}
\definecolor{c5}{HTML}{d8d9d9}
\definecolor{c6}{HTML}{ff8091}


\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
date, gdp, nfsec, gov, house, nfcorp
%1Q08, 8.7, 119.6, 36.4, 23.0, 60.1
%2Q08, 7.8, 118.1, 35.7, 22.7, 59.7
3Q08, 6.6, 109.6, 31.9, 20.8, 56.8
4Q08, 3.0, 106.9, 31.0, 19.7, 56.0
1Q09, 0.8, 113.9, 32.5, 20.1, 61.1
2Q09, 2.0, 129.6, 37.6, 23.1, 68.6
3Q09, 3.8, 141.1, 41.5, 25.6, 73.6
4Q09, 6.4, 141.4, 42.2, 25.9, 73.0
1Q10, 9.2, 138.9, 41.1, 25.9, 71.5
2Q10, 8.6, 135.0, 39.6, 25.1, 69.9
3Q10, 7.8, 139.1, 40.7, 26.5, 71.5
4Q10, 7.9, 138.9, 40.2, 26.7, 71.7
1Q11, 7.9, 139.5, 40.1, 26.9, 72.2
2Q11, 7.4, 139.1, 39.8, 27.0, 71.9
3Q11, 7.0, 130.4, 36.3, 25.1, 68.8
4Q11, 6.3, 131.5, 36.0, 25.4, 69.9
1Q12, 6.0, 136.3, 37.2, 26.2, 72.6
2Q12, 5.6, 135.9, 36.4, 26.1, 73.1
3Q12, 5.6, 141.9, 37.7, 27.4, 76.4
4Q12, 5.7, 145.1, 38.1, 28.2, 78.3
1Q13, 5.5, 148.3, 38.4, 28.5, 81.1
2Q13, 5.7, 148.2, 37.5, 28.6, 81.8
3Q13, 5.7, 150.9, 37.7, 29.3, 83.6
4Q13, 5.6, 153.3, 38.4, 29.8, 85.0
1Q14, 5.4, 155.6, 38.9, 30.0, 86.5
2Q14, 5.3, 160.8, 40.1, 31.1, 89.4
3Q14, 5.1, 159.0, 39.2, 30.6, 89.0
4Q14, 5.0, 158.5, 39.1, 30.2, 89.0
1Q15, 4.9, 161.5, 39.2, 30.4, 91.6
2Q15, 4.8, 167.5, 40.8, 31.6, 94.9
3Q15, 4.8, 166.6, 40.4, 31.4, 94.6
4Q15, 4.8, 170.4, 41.4, 32.3, 96.5
1Q16, 5.3, 180.8, 44.2, 34.3, 102.0
2Q16, 5.4, 182.2, 45.3, 35.3, 101.4
3Q16, 5.3, 184.3, 46.1, 36.5, 101.5
4Q16, 5.6, 179.3, 45.2, 35.7, 98.1
1Q17, 5.3, 184.5, 46.8, 37.1, 100.5
2Q17, 5.4, 186.3, 47.4, 37.9, 100.9
3Q17, 5.7, 188.6, 47.9, 38.9, 101.6
4Q17, 5.7, 190.2, 48.3, 39.7, 102.0
1Q18, 5.9, 193.0, 49.0, 40.5, 103.4
2Q18, 5.6, 181.3, 46.2, 38.4, 96.6
3Q18, 5.2, 177.7, 45.5, 38.4, 93.7
4Q18, 4.8, 180.9, 47.0, 39.4, 94.4
1Q19, 4.5, 190.5, 49.4, 41.2, 99.8
2Q19, 4.5, 192.2, 50.6, 42.0, 99.6
3Q19, 4.4, 187.9, 49.9, 41.3, 96.5
}\bcharttwelve

\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/new ybar legend/.style={
        /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
            \draw[##1,/tikz/.cd,yshift=-0.05cm, xshift = +0.38cm
            ]
            (0cm,0cm) rectangle (0.6em,0.6em);},},              
}

\pgfplotsset{every non boxed x axis/.append style={x axis line style=-},}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\small
\begin{axis}[ybar stacked/.append style={new ybar legend},
width = 13cm,
height = 6cm,
bar width=3mm,
axis lines=left,
axis y line* = left,
enlarge x limits={0.01, upper},
stack plots = y,
%
% y ticks and label
ylabel={\% of GDP},
ylabel shift = 1pt,
ymin = 1,
ytick distance = 50,
%
% x ticks and label
xtick=data,
%xticklabels from table={\bcharttwelve}{date},  
table/x expr = \coordindex,   
xticklabel={\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{Mod(\ticknum,4)}% 4 is the distance
\ifnum\itest=0
\pgfmathparse{element(\ticknum,0)}\pgfmathresult
\fi},                  
x tick label style = {rotate=90},
%
% legend
legend cell align={left},
legend style = {fill = none, draw=none,
    legend columns=2, at={(0.5,1.28)}, anchor=north,
    /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=2em},
},
]
%
% plots
\addplot [new ybar legend, c1, fill, draw opacity = 0]
table [y=gov] from \bcharttwelve \closedcycle;
\addlegendentry{General government};
\addplot [new ybar legend, c3, fill, draw opacity = 0]
table [y=house] from \bcharttwelve \closedcycle;
\addlegendentry{Households};
\addplot [new ybar legend, c5, fill, draw opacity = 0]
table [y=nfcorp] from \bcharttwelve \closedcycle;
\addlegendentry{Non-financial corporations};
\addplot [new ybar legend, c6, fill, draw opacity = 0]
table [y=nfsec] from \bcharttwelve \closedcycle;
\addlegendentry{Non-financial sector};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've been producing a lot of charts lately, and despite my adoration of LaTeX, it's been very interesting discovering all these 'holes' in LaTeX's (or at least, PGF's) native plotting ability. You've answered many of my questions and I learn something new every time - thank you :)

Comment: @TheveshTheva You're welcome! As long as these holes are no black holes I think we are fine. ;-)