# pgfplots - skipi data and fix symbolic tick labels

Tags: pgfplots

How to skip some points without skip x tick label? where is december?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{quant.csv}
month;2017;2018
January;nan;474500
February;457370;476580
March;443320;454930
April;353570;377600
May;400070;410190
June;392270;423280
July;343680;359340
August;271590;409120
September;312700;311910
October;388600;463960
November;367510;222960
December;291360;nan
\end{filecontents}


\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon, header = true]
{quant.csv}\wastetable


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width  = \textwidth,
height = 0.5625\textwidth,
major x tick style = transparent,
smooth,
%   stack plots=y,
%   area style,
line width = 1 pt, 
ymajorgrids = true,
yminorgrids = true,
ylabel = {kg},
axis x line=center,
axis y line=left,
xtick = data,
scaled y ticks = false,
xticklabels from table = {\wastetable}{month},
enlarge x limits=0.05,
unbounded coords=jump,
ylabel style={rotate=0, xshift=5mm},
x tick label style={font=\small,align=right, rotate = 45, anchor = east},%text width=3.0cm},
legend cell align=left,
legend style={%
    at={(0.98,1.1)},
    anchor=south east,
    column sep=1ex,
    font = \scriptsize}%%
]
\addplot[style={red, mark=*}]  table[x expr = \coordindex, y index = 1] {\wastetable};
\addlegendentry{2017};
\addplot[style={blue, mark=*}] table[x expr = \coordindex, y index = 2] {\wastetable};
\addlegendentry{2018};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why `December` gets skipped is that the corresponding y value in the first plot is `nan`. So the standard keys of pgfplots seem not to give you quite what you want, and one can fix this similarly to the problem of [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/543652/194703). Here the function `element` is a slight variation of the version from the previous answer, neither of them is perfect. This has to do with the fact that I was unable to understand what `\pgfplotstablegetcolumn` does in detail. So I ended up with

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17} 
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{element}{3}{\begingroup
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}%
\expandafter\pgfplotstablevertcat\expandafter\mytable\csname#3\endcsname%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myindex}{max(0,#1)}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mycol}{#2}%
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\myindex}{[index]\mycol}\of\mytable%#1=row, #2=column
\edef\pgfmathresult{\pgfplotsretval}%
\pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult
\endgroup}


\begin{filecontents}{quant.csv}
month;2017;2018
January;nan;474500
February;457370;476580
March;443320;454930
April;353570;377600
May;400070;410190
June;392270;423280
July;343680;359340
August;271590;409120
September;312700;311910
October;388600;463960
November;367510;222960
December;291360;nan
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon, header = true]
{quant.csv}\wastetable
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\wastetable}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\numrows}{\pgfplotsretval-1}%
\begin{axis}[
width  = \textwidth,
height = 0.5625\textwidth,
major x tick style = transparent,
smooth,
line width = 1 pt, 
ymajorgrids = true,
yminorgrids = true,
ylabel = {kg},
axis x line=center,
axis y line=left,
scaled y ticks = false,
xtick={0,...,\numrows},
xticklabel={\pgfmathparse{element(\ticknum,0,"wastetable")}\pgfmathresult},                  
enlarge x limits=0.05,
enlarge y limits=0.05,
unbounded coords=jump,
ylabel style={rotate=0, xshift=5mm},
x tick label style={font=\small,align=right, rotate = 45, anchor = east},%text width=3.0cm},
legend cell align=left,
legend style={%
    at={(0.98,1.1)},
    anchor=south east,
    column sep=1ex,
    font = \scriptsize}%%
]
\addplot[style={red, mark=*}]  table[x expr = \coordindex, y index = 1] {\wastetable};
\addlegendentry{2017};
\addplot[style={blue, mark=*}] table[x expr = \coordindex, y index = 2] {\wastetable};
\addlegendentry{2018};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]