# pgfplots use data from previous row

Tags: pgfplots

I have a data file like so:

```
year  n      cpi
1960  2000   27
1961  2050   29
1963  2200   33
```

For 1961, I want to plot `(2050 / 29) * 27`.  For 1963 I want to plot `(2200 / 33) * 27`.

Basically, in a spreadsheet, this is a column `=(B2/C2)*C$2` expanded down (so `C$2` is always `C$2`, but the others increment each row).

I can't figure out how to make `pgfplots` reference row n, just `\thisrow{}`.  I want to reference `\rowdata[year=1960]{cpi}` or something.  Can't find this anywhere.

Comment: Welcome! You can use the `element` function from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/544057/194703). If you post a complete example, I will be happy to spell this out in detail.

Comment: Thanks! That's a lot more complex than I figured.  I'd have thought the main package would handle that normally, e.g. for column `x` contains value `n` give me column `y`; or give me column `y` from row `n`.  This will work.

Comment: I fail to understand your last statement. In general it helps to be precise, and to add a minimal working example to the question. You are telling me that what I am suggesting is too complicated. Fair enough. Could actually well be since I do not seem to understand what you are asking.